# how to draw a line with canvas that line show on a textview or any thing else?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Hi guys i just want to draw lines on any component on a Activity i need that for my application so how can i do that?

```
public class myLinearlayout extends LinearLayout {
private Paint paints = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
public myLinearlayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paints.setAntiAlias(true);
    paints.setStrokeWidth(10f);
    paints.setColor(Color.RED);
    paints.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paints.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paints);
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("draw::", "onTouchEvent: "+event.getX()+","+event.getY());
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(event.getX(),event.getY());
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(event.getX(),event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            try {
                path.reset();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("draww::", e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        default:
            return  false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}}
```

in this code drawed line appears under the text view i want it on the textview could any body help me? I'm making a word puzzle game so i need to draw a line on any textviews that i made so i need this and this code just draws lines under them

and my xml code is

```
<com.example.saman.patterntest.myLinearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: if you want tit on the textview, then you have to extend the textview, and draw on it

Comment: override `dispatchDraw`, call `super` method and do your drawing

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it doesn't work because i have 9 textviews in my orginal app and there when i draw it just draw on one not all of them it just draw on the textview that draw started on it

Comment: sure, your welcome